# How to fix DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global'

Tags: node-webkit

I tried to open a new window in node webkit but in the background console it throws the following error:

> DeprecationWarning: 'root' is deprecated, use 'global'

I am using NWJS v0.15.3 but this problem is not mentioned in their known issues.

Below is my sample code:

```
var newWin = nw.Window.open('app/newWin/newWin.html', {
    new_instance: true
}, function () {
    // opened
    console.log("opened");
});
```

Comment: Oh, it's already fixed in v0.15.4.

Answer (score 3):

It is not an Error, it is a Warning. But
it may be a symptom of an error.

Somewhere in your code or the code of some library
you are using there is a reference to the global 
variable 'root'.

That is not an error by itself because such a variable
does exist and is an alias to 'global'. But developers
are advised against using it, you are supposed to
use 'global' instead, as documented at:
https://nodejs.org/api/deprecations.html .

Seeing the warning may INDICATE 
there is an error in your code. Maybe
you are UNINTENTIONALLY reading or writing
to the global variable 'root'.

In my case I had a variable named 'rootSpec'.
But when I was supposed to  read its value
I had misspelled it as 'root' instead.

So I saw the deprecation warning on the log
and started looking for any references
to 'root' and found the one place where 
I was using it, wrongly.

My (erroneous) code could have 
written something to some fields of 'root'.
That could have in effect overwritten some
built-in globals without me even realizing 
that was going on. That could have  created a hard to detect, hard to diagnose
hard to fix bug.

Therefore seeing the deprecation warning
really alerted me against a possible
killer-bug in my program.

Answer (score -3):

Your code is incorrect. Check documentation here: http://docs.nwjs.io/en/latest/References/Window/#windowopenurl-options-callback

```
nw.Window.open('app/newWin/newWin.html', {
    new_instance: true
}, function (newWin ) {
    // opened
    console.log("opened", newWin);
});
```